# Do I need to purchase a Positive SSL while buying a domain?

Tags: ssl, certificate, domain, web-hosting

I am new to creating and hosting websites and want to clear a few things about buying domain names and SSL certificates.
I created my website using [Hugo Academic](https://themes.gohugo.io/academic/) and now I want to deploy it. In their [documentation for domain name](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/domain/) they suggested [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/) for registering a domain and [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) for deployment.

However when I searched for a domian on Namecheap I was also pointed to some additional things like **Positive SSL** as you can see below -
[image: namecheap]

I need to know if I need to purchase a Positive SSL from Namecheap along with the domain too?
What would be the consequences of not getting a positive ssl certificate from them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Domains are completely independent from TLS certificates; Namecheap is just trying to upsell.

(There is no such term as "[a positive ssl](https://i.imgflip.com/2oygi7.jpg)" in general – that's just a product marketing name used by Sectigo aka Comodo CA, which appears to be a partner of Namecheap.)

If you need a certificate for hosting HTTPS websites (or other TLS-based services) on your own server, you will be able to purchase one at any time from any CA authority you want (including for free from "Let's Encrypt"), as long as the CA can verify your domain ownership.

But according to the Netlify website, they will automatically set everything up for you as part of the hosting service, so using your own certificate would be a waste.

Comment: if I opt out of positive ssl then i wouldn't face any issues with "Your connection is not secure" and to add "Security exception" for those that browse my website. Netlify would take care of that, right?

Comment: As netlify uses Let's encrypt to create an SSL certificate and us widely accepted you don't need an SSL certificate from PositveSSL + in fact doing so is likely to be a waste or counterproductive.